# Azure Devops - SSDT DB build error - writing model.xml

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

I get the following build error for my SSDT project in Azure DevOps:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'd:\a\1\s\SSDTPROJECTNAME\SSDTPROJECTNAMEobj\Release\Model.xml'.
```

Earlier in the build it attempts to write the Model.xml file to an invalid path:

```
SqlBuild:
  Creating a model to represent the project...
    Loading project references...
    Loading project files...
    Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
    Validating the project model...
    Writing model to SSDTPROJECTNAMEobj\Release\Model.xml...
```

For some reason it fails to concatenate my project folder name with obj\Release\Model.xml. But when I build locally it writes the model.xml to a valid location. For the project folder I'm using a variable called $(projectDir) set to my project folder name.

I'm using VSBuild@1 with the windows-latest vmImage.

Here's my task:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: "Build DB project"
    inputs:
      solution: "$(projectDir)\SSDTPROJECTNAME.sqlproj"
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
      configuration: "$(BuildConfiguration)"
      clean: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'projectDir' variable is preserved key word for VS Build.  If you change to a different variable should fix the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019